# select all years that greater than 5 years ago from year today

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
 a          b
 1          2009
 2          2007
 3          2006
 4          2010
 5          2011
```

How I will select all years that greater than 5 years ago from year today?

```
So it would be like 2013(year today) - 5 = 2008
 a          b
 1          2009
 4          2010
 5          2011
```

I tried this:

```
select * from table1 where b > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 5
```

I use smallint as datatype of column b instead of date because I will only store the year. Is it safe to use small int for storing year?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were close:

```
select * from table1 where b > YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 5
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `b < year(current_timestamp) -5`? less than means before, which means greater than 5 years ago from today, right?

Comment: English descriptions don't always line up with expectations, which is why sample data and expected results are so important.  Look at OP's data; in 2013, they wanted years 2009. 2010. and 2011 (and NOT 2006 and 2007)

Answer (score 12):

```
select * from table1 where b > DATEADD(YEAR,-5,GETDATE())
```

should work as well